# AWS CDK: how to target an Elastic Beanstalk Environment with a Route53 Alias Record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

To create an Elastic Beanstalk Application and Environment I have the following code:

```js
// this: the class instance extending Construct

const application = new CfnApplication(this, 'Application', {
  applicationName: 'some-name'
});
const environment = new CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
  environmentName: 'production',
  applicationName: application.applicationName,
  platformArn: 'arn::of::plaform',
  solutionStackName: 'a-valid-stack-name'
});
```

Creating an alias record in Route53 requires a target implementing `IAliasRecordTarget`

```
const record = new AliasRecord(this, 'ARecord', {
 recordName: 'a-record',
 target: ?
 zone: zone
});
```

How can I use the environment as target? Looking for classes implementing IAliasRecordTarget in the aws-cdk repo does not yield many candidates beside cloudfront distribution and base load balancer

Comment: beanstalk creates load balancer as well , you could use that or you can simply use the beanstalk dns name,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` prop expects an object with a `bind()` function returning `dnsName`, `evaluateTargetHealth` and `hostedZoneId` (see [AWS::Route53::RecordSet AliasTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html) and the [implementation of `AliasRecord`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/v0.32.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-route53/lib/records/alias.ts)).

You can do the following:

```js
const record = new AliasRecord(this, 'ARecord', {
  recordName: 'a-record',
  target: {
    bind: (): AliasRecordTargetProps => ({
      dnsName: environment.attrEndpointUrl,
      hostedZoneId: 'Z14LCN19Q5QHIC' // for us-east-2
    })
  },
  zone: zone
});
```

See [AWS Elastic Beanstalk endpoints and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elasticbeanstalk.html) for a list of hosted zone IDs if using another region or [Elastic Load Balancing endpoints and quotas](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/elb.html) when the environment is load-balanced.

**UPDATE 2018-05-28**: `asAliasRecordTarget` is now `bind` in `aws-cdk` version 0.32.0

Comment: The link does not provide any hosted zone id at all. Maybe it changed ? How can we do now ?

Comment: Edit of my previous comment :
For people like me struggling to find the table : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elasticbeanstalk.html. 
  
Also environment.environmentEndpointUrl is undefined. If we use environment.attrEndpointUrl, the endpoint is the one of the elb (not the beanstalk one). So you must use the hostedZoneId of the elb in corresponding region : https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/general/latest/gr/elb.html

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for a solution in case of a single instance environment:

1. Set the `cnamePrefix` in your EBS Environment to a value you like (eg. 'my-app'). This results in a url you can use later as part of the `dnsName` to create an A-record;
2. Create an `AliasRecordTarget`:

```js
const record: IAliasRecordTarget = {
                bind: (): AliasRecordTargetConfig => ({
                  dnsName: `${cnamePrefix}.${this.region}.elasticbeanstalk.com`,
                  hostedZoneId: 'Z2NYPWQ7DFZAZH' // Lookup ID or create a mapper: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roadworker/Aws/Route53 
                })
              };
```

3. Create the `A-record`:

```js
// Route53 alias record for the EBS app
new ARecord(this, 'ebs-alias-record', {
              recordName: `my-app.mydomain.com.`,
              target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(record),
              zone: hostedZone
            })
```

** Edit **

To get the value of the `hostedZone` variable you can lookup your zone by using:

`HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'zone-lookup', {domainName: 'my-app.mydomain.com'});`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround that allows you to forward requests to the EBS environment URL (not the load balancer).

```js
import { ARecord, RecordTarget, HostedZone, AliasRecordTargetConfig } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53';

// Environment URL for my EBS app.
const EBS_ENV_URL = 'mysampleenvironment.eba-8mmp67ym.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com';

// Id of the hosted zone in the region your EBS environment is located.
const EBS_ENV_HOSTED_ZONE_ID = 'Z117KPS5GTRQ2G';

const aliasRecord = new ARecord(stack, 'AliasRecord', {
  recordName: DOMAIN,
  target: RecordTarget.fromAlias({
    bind: (): AliasRecordTargetConfig => ({
      dnsName: EBS_ENV_URL,
      hostedZoneId: EBS_ENV_HOSTED_ZONE_ID 
    })
  }),
  zone: HostedZone.fromLookup(stack, 'WebsiteHostedZone', {
    domainName: DOMAIN
  })
});
```

This workaround is basically implementing a custom [`IAliasRecordTarget`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.IAliasRecordTarget.html).

1. Hardcode the [EBS app’s environment URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-get-domain-name) into the `dnsName` prop.
2. Visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elasticbeanstalk.html and find the hosted zone id that matches the region of the EBS app’s environment. This value will need to be hardcoded in the `hostedZoneId` prop.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution and comment posted by @jogold,
using the `HostedZoneProvider`, to retreive your own hosted zone and
using the zone id of the Elastic Beanstalk Hosted zone as target

```js
const zone = new HostedZoneProvider(this, {
            domainName: props.domainName
}).findAndImport(this, 'a-hosted-zone');

const ebsRegionHostedZoneId = 'Z117KPS5GTRQ2G' // us-east-1

const record = new AliasRecord(this, 'ARecord', {
  recordName: 'a-record',
  target: {
    asAliasRecordTarget: (): AliasRecordTargetProps => ({
      dnsName: environment.environmentEndpointUrl,
      // the id of the hosted zone in your region
      hostedZoneId: ebsRegionHostedZoneId
    })
  },
  // your hosted zone
  zone: zone
});
```

Comment: Not sure this will give you the "constant" hosted zone id used by Elastic Beanstalk Service (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#elasticbeanstalk_region), this is to query for hosted zone id in your account.

Comment: @jogold, Indeed that makes sense, there are two urls in two hosted zones: the alias record links the url in the hosted zone of the client to and url in  the elastic beanstalk hosted zone